# How to check if any values match each other (without predefining any values)

Tags: r, filter, match, tidyverse

Probably a very quick one - I want to know how to check if multiple values match each other (without predefining any values).

For example, the "difference" column below could contain any values between 0-100. Whenever there are multiple rows with matching values (in the example below, 2 rows match, but it could be all 3, or none at all), I want to filter those and take them forward.

```
Stim        difference

1 book1      30
2 book2      30
3 book3      15
```

Is there some kind of solution with filter, along these lines:

```
...
   filter(difference == difference) %>%
   ...
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: So you only want to have unique values of difference? In order words, do you want to remove the duplicated differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if you want to remove duplicates or only have duplicates, so here are both solutions.

```
library(tidyverse)

#sample data
book_data <- tibble(book = paste0("book", 1:3), difference = c(30,30, 15)) 

#remove duplicates
book_data %>%
  filter(!duplicated(difference))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   book  difference
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 book1         30
#> 2 book3         15

#Keep only duplicates
book_data %>%
  group_by(difference) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   difference [1]
#>   book  difference
#>   <chr>      <dbl>
#> 1 book1         30
#> 2 book2         30
```

Comment: The second solution was exactly what I was looking for, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `data.table::rleid()` and `!duplicated()` to filter for consecutive duplicates. If you need non-consecutive duplicates removed you can just use `!duplicated()`. Hope this helps!

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  filter(!duplicated(data.table::rleid(difference)))

   Stim difference
1 book1         30
2 book3         15
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "Stim        difference

1 book1      30
2 book2      30
3 book3      15")
```